# Return a key/value pair from an object that specifies itself which is the key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract a key/value pair from an object, where the key is specified as the value of the property "a" in that same object.

For example:

```
{a: 1, 1: b}
```

Output should be:

```
{1: b}
```

So the path to follow is like: "a" → 1 → "b"

First I need to access the value of 'a' i.e. '1' and from '1' I need the value, i.e. 'b'

How can I achieve that in an elegant way?

Comment: So go ahead and try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) syntax:

```js
let input = {a :1 , 1: "b"};

let output = { [input.a]: input[input.a] };

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back to this answer?